# var_dump shows null, but value is returned from query

Tags: php, php-5.5

Value  is returned from query for `$taxonomy_id` , but var_dump($taxonomy_id) shows null.

```
 $stmt = $db->query("SELECT rt.taxonomy_id FROM request_taxonomy rt LEFT JOIN request_aspects ra ON ra.aspect_id = rt.request_aspects_id
                WHERE rt.requests_id = $requestID and rt.sort_order=$old_sort_order");

            $taxonomy_id = $stmt->fetchColumn();    


            for($i=0;$i<$trcount;$i++)
                {


            $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO request_meta (requests_id,request_taxonomy_id,meta_value,staff_id) VALUES($requestID,$taxonomy_id,?,93)");
            $stmt->bindValue(1, $_REQUEST['paraname'.$i]);
            $stmt->execute();

            $taxonomy_id+=6;    

             }
```

Due to which `$taxonomy_id+=6;`  is not working , despite all the efforts I have put in to make it work.

`$taxonomy_id++` works, but I want to add to add a constant number to it.

Comment: what do you get on var_dump($taxonomy_id) ??

Comment: it is coming as null, but the query executes with actual value , say 59038

Comment: if it is null then how can you add a constant number to it ??

Comment: $taxonomy_id inserts correct value in the query used, but in var_dump it is showing null

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO request_meta (requests_id,request_taxonomy_id,meta_value,staff_id) "
        . "VALUES($requestID,?,?,93)");

for ($i = 0; $i < $trcount; $i++) {
  $stmt->execute([$taxonomy_id, $_REQUEST['paraname' . $i]]);
  $taxonomy_id += 6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php): `PDOStatement::fetchColumn()` will "Returns a single column from the next row of a result set or FALSE if there are no more rows."

So, if it return FALSE (boolean), then you cannot to use incrementing operator (+=).